# JavaFX FXML ListView always disabled

Tags: java, listview, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a ListView in JavaFX, which I added through FXML and then in the Controller class I am loading it. I am trying to load some xml files from a folder and output it as a ListView. I have managed to do that but I did not manage to make the ListView items selectable. I tried searching on google and the only thing I found was people trying to disable the ListView items.

My code, that inits the ListView looks like this:

```
    ObservableList<String> ol = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ol.add("+");
    listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    listView.setEditable(true);
    try {
        Files.walk(Paths.get("res/tasks/"))
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .forEach(i -> {
                    ol.add(i.toFile().getName());
                });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    listView.setItems(ol);
```

and it looks like this: [image: ListView items are disabled]

I have also tried modifying the parameters in SceneBuilder for the ListView but without any success.

For any help, I thank you!

EDIT: I am using a Mac is it possible that Java runs different on mac?

Comment: Is it possible you have set a style or a property through the FXML or in another place in your code? Please try to make a complete self-contained example (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ).

Comment: @sillyfly No :/ I set editable and disabled just to be sure to true and still it does not work

Comment: "_I set editable and disabled just to be sure to true_" which means disabled to true ? make it false.